# How to load new screen?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new to Windows 7 application development. I'm not getting how to load new xaml screen from main xaml screen say onclick of button. Can anyone kindly help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/<nameofproj>;component/<nameofpage>.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

I tried it and it works fine

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean navigating to other XAML page? If so, use:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/OtherPage.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just navigate!!

Create an event handler for that button, e.g:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/yourProject;component/newPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

You can come back to this page later by using:

```
NavigationService.GoBack();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Simple Navigation:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/OtherPage.xaml" , UriKind.Relative));
```

### Navigation with value exchanging between pages:

```
NavigationService.Navigate( new Uri( String.Format( "/OtherPage.xaml?name={0}&address={1}",
          Uri.EscapeDataString( nameVal), Uri.EscapeDataString( addressVal ) ), 
          UriKind.Relative ) );
```

Here nameVal and addressVal are values to be passed to other page.